# iOS: Problem Loading Audio from URL in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, avaudioplayer, quicktime

I am loading an MP3 podcast stream into a UIWebView as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/podcasts/downloader/download.mp3?af=a&f=10109"]]; 

    [webView loadRequest:request];

}
```

The stream appears to load, and then a UIAlert appears saying:

```
An error occurred while exchanging data. "Plug-in handled load"
```

And immediately after the stream loads properly in QuickTime and plays. Why is this alert appearing?

I'd prefer not to use AVAudioPlayer to play the stream, but rather QuickTime.

Comment: AVAudioPlayer _is_ QuickTime.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on iOS, the URL is pointing to localhost, and there are probably no web server on the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can just ignore that error. It is to let you know that quicktime is handling the load.

```
//Playing audio gives error that says plug-in handled load
if([error.domain isEqualToString:@"WebKitErrorDomain"] && error.code == 204)
{
    // Ignore it 
}
```